# Witcher Adventure Game

Tags: discussion, questions

In the [Witcher Adventure Game](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/the-witcher-adventure-game/), you can play as one of four characters trying to complete a set of quest.

*Would asking what are the optimal strategies for each character be on-topic?*

On one hand, I think it should be since there must be some better strategy as others which can help you complete the rightly chosen quests. On the other hand, this might be too general to give a suitable answer.

Comment: There is a substantial number of strategy questions for other games , and it looks like most of these haven't been closed (example: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/14069/14416). I suppose this means that those questions are on-topic. If they are, then the Witcher strategy questions also should be on-topic.

Comment: And yet [one of my questions on strategy was closed](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13750/what-is-a-solid-basic-strategy-for-surviving-ghost-story)...

Comment: But it has been closed as "too broad" not as an "offtopic".

Comment: Indeed but I cannot fathom that Ghost Story is so complex that there are not some solid advice as to how to win games, especially on lower difficulties. The same could be said of Eldritch Horror or Pandemic: it's just too complicated.

Comment: @Sardathrion I think the issues are that folks are pretty skeptical of non-factual questions here to begin with, and what's "basic" isn't always as specific as it seems. There might be dozens of individually basic strategy ideas, once you ask enough people, but by the time you put it all together you're basically giving full strategy advice, not just basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I asked the questions and they have neither attracted downvotes nor been closed, I am assuming that they are fine.